# Show that $\sin(x),\sin(2x), \dots , \sin(k-1)x$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have the space of differentiable functions $f: [0, \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ with the $L^2$-inner product:

$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^{\pi} f(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x.
$

I want to show that the following collection of functions is orthogonal:

$\sin(x),\sin(2x), \dots , \sin(k-1)x$.

My hunch is that I should try to show that

$
\langle 1, \sin(nx) \rangle = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(nx) \mathrm{d}x=0.
$

But is this a valid way of show that the collection of functions is orthogonal, since 1 is not part of the collection of functions above? Should I instead show that $\langle 0, \sin(nx) \rangle = 0$?

Comment: The inner product is defined wrongly. The integral must go up to $\pi$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right!

Comment: Neither $1$ nor $0$ is in you list of functions. You only need to test $\langle \sin(mx), \sin(nx) \rangle$ where $1 \le m \ne  n \le k-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that the inner product between any two distinct functions in your collection is $0$. This is the definition of orthogonality. So prove that for distinct $m,n$ we have $\langle \sin(mx),\sin(nx)\rangle=0$. To evaluate the integral you can use the following identity:

$\sin(mx)\sin(nx)=\frac{\cos((m-n)x)-\cos((m+x)x)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sin (jx)\sin (kx)=\frac 1  2[\cos (j-k)x) -\cos (j+k)x]$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,\,b\in\Bbb N$ with $a\ne b$,$$\int_0^\pi\sin ax\sin bx dx=\frac12\int_0^\pi(\cos(a-b)x-\cos(a+b)x)dx.$$Since $a-b\ne0$, each cosine contributes $0$ to the integrand.