# Show that $\{1, \cos x, \sin x, \cos(2x), \sin(2x), \dots, \cos(nx), \sin(nx)\}$ is an orthogonal set of V .

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, projection

Suppose $V := CR([0, 2\pi])$ is the collection of real valued functions on $[0, 2\pi]$
with inner product given by
$$\langle f,g\rangle:= \int_0^{2\pi}f(x)g(x)\,dx$$

Show that $$S_n := \{1, \cos x, \sin x, \cos(2x), \sin(2x), \dots , \cos(nx), \sin(nx)\}$$ is an orthogonal set of V.

Find the orthogonal projection of a function $f \in V$ on $span(S_n).$ Particularly find the orthogonal projections of the function $x$  on $span(S_2)$ and $span(S_3).$

(And we know for $n \to \infty,$ the orthogonal projection of a function $f$ on $S_n$ is nothing but the Fourier series expansion of the function $f$).

Comment: For “Un” in the last paragraph, do you mean $S_n$ or something else?

Comment: I meant Sn ,sorry for the typo I'll correct it in the question  Thanks for pointing out @ThomasAndrews

Comment: To show that $S_n$ is orthogonal, you need to show that for any two distinct functions in $S_n$, their inner product, according the inner product you give, is 0. This follows from a case analysis explicitly computing these integrals using basic trig identities. It looks like there is another post that provides some guidance here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3603015/show-that-sinx-sin2x-dots-sink-1x-is-orthogonal?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos (a x) \sin (b x)=\frac{1}{2} (\sin (a x+b x)-\sin (a x-b x))$$
Integrating
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos (a x) \sin (b x)\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{1}{2} (\sin (a x+b x)-\sin (a x-b x))\,dx=$$
$$=\left[\frac{\cos (x (a-b))}{2 (a-b)}-\frac{\cos (x (a+b))}{2 (a+b)}\right]_0^{2\pi}=\\=\frac{\cos (2 \pi  (a-b))}{2 (a-b)}-\frac{\cos (2 \pi  (a+b))}{2 (a+b)}-\left(\frac{1}{2 (a-b)}-\frac{1}{2 (a+b)}\right)=0,\;\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Edit

For the other products $\sin(ax)\sin(bx);\;\cos(ax)\cos(bx)$ a similar procedure leads to the same result.